# SQLAlchemy: retrieve all episodes from favorite_series of specific user

Tags: python, database, many-to-many, sqlalchemy, flask

I have user who can have his favorite series and there are episodes which have series as foreign key and I am trying to retrieve all episodes from favorite series of user.
I am using Flask-SQLAlchemy.

Database:

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# cross table for user-series
favorite_series = db.Table('favorite_series',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('series_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('series.id'))
)

# user
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    favorite_series = db.relationship('Series', secondary=favorite_series,
        backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))

# series
class Series(db.Model):
     __tablename__ = 'series'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

# episode
class Episode(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'episode'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    series_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('series.id'))
    series = db.relationship('Series',
        backref=db.backref('episodes', lazy='dynamic'))
```

Friend helped me with SQL

```
select user_id,series.name,episode.name from (favorite_series left join series on favorite_series.series_id = series.id) left join episode on episode.series_id = series.id where user_id=1;
```

Altough, I want it in SQLAlchemy API, but can't manage to get it working.

**EDIT**:

My final working result:

```
episodes = Episode.query.filter(Episode.series_id.in_(x.id for x in g.user.favorite_series)).filter(Episode.air_time!=None).order_by(Episode.air_time)
```

Comment: Are you using the SQLAlchemy ORM ? flask-sqlalchemy does I think...

Comment: I am really new in this :) You tell me :)

`>>> s = Series.query.get(1)
>>> s.episodes
<sqlalchemy.orm.dynamic.AppenderBaseQuery object at 0x9d0254c>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you don't seem to be declaring your table names? 
Also, the whole point of bothering with orm is so you never have to write sql queries:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import orm
import sqlalchemy as db
Base = declarative_base()

favorite_series = db.Table('favorite_series', Base.metadata,
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('User.id')),
    db.Column('series_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Series.id'))
)
class Episode(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Episode'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    season = db.Column(db.Integer)
    episode_num = db.Column(db.Integer)
    series_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Series.id'))

    def __init__(self, season, episode_num, series_id):
        self.season = season
        self.episode_num = episode_num
        self.series_id = series_id

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.series.title + \
               ' S' + str(self.season) + \
               'E' + str(self.episode_num)

class Series(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Series'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String)
    episodes = orm.relationship('Episode', backref='series')

    def __init__(self, title):
        self.title = title

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.title

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'User'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    favorite_series = orm.relationship('Series', 
        secondary=favorite_series, backref='users')

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name
```

Now you can just access the attributes of your objects and let sql alchemy deal with keeping you DB in sync and issuing queries.

```
engine = db.create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
session = orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)()
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

lt = User('Ludovic Tiako')
the_wire = Series('The Wire')
friends = Series('Friends')
session.add_all([lt, the_wire, friends])
session.commit() # need to commit here to generate the id fields

tw_s01e01 = Episode(1,1,the_wire.id)
tw_s01e02 = Episode(1,2,the_wire.id)
f_s01e01 = Episode(1,1,friends.id)
f_s01e02 = Episode(1,2,friends.id)
f_s01e03 = Episode(1,3,friends.id)

session.add_all([tw_s01e01, tw_s01e02, 
                f_s01e01, f_s01e02, f_s01e03])
session.commit()


the_wire.episodes # > [The Wire S1E1, The Wire S1E2]
friends.episodes # > [Friends S1E1, Friends S1E2, Friends S1E3]
```

Finally, to answer your question:

```
lt.favorite_series.append(the_wire)
session.commit()
lt.favorite_series # > [The Wire]
[s.episodes for s in lt.favorite_series] # >> [[The Wire S1E1, The Wire S1E2]]
```

Comment: But I need to apply some other filters I did not mention.

I use this when I dont care about user:

`episodes = Episode.query.filter(Episode.air_time>=t.strftime('%Y%m%d')).order_by(Episode.air_time)`

Comment: And I want to use same filter and order for episodes for specific user.

Comment: Once u have `fav_episodes = [s.episodes.id for s in lt.favorite_series]`
just add to your query `query.filter(Episode.id.in_(fav_episodes))`

Comment: + as I meantioned in first post I use Flak-SQLAlchemy so I don't need to define tablenames etc. many stuff are taken care of for me because this is meant for web site made with Flask you dont seem to be doing anything with Flask-SQLAlchemy in your example

Comment: You should use `db.Model` instead of `Base` and `db.session` instead of creating one, and the engine also, etc. Flask-SQLAlchemy provides you with these. And the way you are doing it will make multiple queries, not one, but it sure does work.

Comment: yeah i used the regular sqlalchemy instead of the flask extension. haven't tried the flask extension yet, but it sounds like it automatically defines all these commonly used variables for you. I should check it out i guess.
@Ondrej Fabry, if you could update your original question with the final code using flask extension, that would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Flask, but from the docs of Flask-SQLAlchemy, it seems it uses declarative, so the ORM. And so, you should have a session. I think it is accessible to you from `db.session`.

Anyway, if those assumptions are true, this is how you should do it:

```
query = db.session.query(User.id, Series.name, Episode.name).filter((Episode.series_id == Series.id) & \
    (User.id == favorite_series.c.user_id) & (Series.id == favorite_series.c.id) & \
    (User.id == 1))
results = query.all();
```

It might not be the exact query you provided, but should do the same.

**UPDATE**: I just checked Flask-SQLALchemy code on [github](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/master/flask_sqlalchemy.py), it seems that `db` is an instance of `SQLAlchemy`, which has a `session` attribute, created by `self.session = self.create_scoped_session(session_options)` which returns a session object. So this should work.

Also, not that by doing that, you won't be using their BaseQuery, although I don't know what that would mean...

Check the documentation to know what to do exactly.

Comment: `db` appears to be the metadata, so the session won't be in there.  The session object is created by `sessionmaker`.

Comment: @wberry `db` is an instance of `SQLAlchemy`. See the code. I added a link, I think this is the way to access the session.

Comment: this throws: AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'user_id'

Comment: @OndrejFabry Right, my bad. It's `favorite_series.c.user_id` (`.c` is for "column"), because favorite_series is a `Table` while the others are `Model` which derive from SQLAlchemy's declarative base.